# Custom default value for Webform's select options component

Tags: 7

I use Drupal 7 with Webform 7.x-3.9.

I have created a new component from type "select options". I also have chosen to display it as a listbox and I've populated it with a few strings from the type "**safe_key|Some readable option**" as expected. Here's an example :

1|Mr.

2|Ms.

3|Miss

Everything works perfectly well and the behavior is the following :

- If I select this component to be mandatory, the display will be "-Select-"
- If I don't select this component to be mandatory, the display will reflect the first string from the "Options" text area. In my example, it will be "Mr."

Now, imagine I want to have "Ms." but don't want to change the order. Nowhere I see this possible. Unfortunately, the "Default value" textfield is only used for tokens...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do, it to put the key value into the default value field, in this case 2, to make `Ms.` the default value of the form. This is what the default value if used for.

Comment: Oh ok, I put the safe key + the option...that's why I couldn't make it work. Thank you !